# Dual boot XP and ubuntu, (XP installed first)

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, windows-xp

I tried to install ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386. While booting from live cd I checked GParted and [details confused me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llZ1K.jpg). As I recently formatted my PC after moving all data to other internal HD, you can see all partitions are empty. Now I have to install ubuntu on D partition. But I see a partition extended 172 GB which I actually don't have. How should I proceed? Also, when I clicked on Windows partitions they appeared on the desktop. Is this mounting?

This is a continuation of the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/398133/dual-boot-xp-and-linux-based-os-information-needed#comment453217_398134).

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda1 is a primary partition.

/dev/sda2 is an extended partition, think 'container' and is 172 gig TOTAL, made up of sda5 thru 9.

And yes, that is mounting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok , so its a total of all the partition, I am installing ubuntu (side by side option), on which drive it will be installed?

Comment: Something has happened ,[Windows partition's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hSDjv.jpg) size decreased.What to do now